how to create table with default date value as the current date in MySQL?
Is there a way to create a table with a field that defaults to the current date value instead of a timestamp?
CREATE TABLE animal (
animal_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
animal_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
animal_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
species VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(10),
entry_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
status VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'present' NOT NULL
);

I have tried using CURRENT_DATE but i got this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE,
status VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'present' NOT NULL
)' at line 7

Can you specify which version of Mysql you are using ?

Current versions of mysql allow arbitrary self-contained expressions but you must enclose them in parenthesis:
DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE)

That said, CURRENT_DATE is the date in the timezone of the current session, so different sessions may use different defaults.  I recommend never using any of the functions that depend on the session timezone (now, current_date, etc).  If you want the field to default to the currrent date in some specific timezone, be explicit about it, in a way that can't vary by session. E.g. for US Pacific time:
DEFAULT (date(convert_tz(utc_timestamp,'+00:00','America/Los_Angeles')))


And I would recommend never ever store datetimes other than in UTC. Its part of the application to determine the current timezone of the user and show the local time properly

@Thallius agreed. but some times it is convenient to store a date (not a datetime)
